# SharedFlow not collecting values in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am making simple code to collect values in shared followed but it not collecting values.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

fun main() {
    val eventBus = EventBus()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        repeat(10) {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
        delay(10.seconds)
        (10..20).forEach {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        eventBus.value.collect {
            println("value comes before interval $it")
        }
    }
}

class EventBus {
    private val _value = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val value: SharedFlow<Int> = _value.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun increment(number: Int) {
        _value.emit(number)
    }
}
```

When I run this code it nothing printing in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your programs stops immediately because you don't use **structured concurrency**, i.e. your coroutines are independent instead of being controlled by a shared coroutine scope. To change that you should use `runBlocking` and avoid `GlobalScope`.

Note that the first batch of events *most likely* won't be collected because the collecting coroutine won't get a chance to start until the emitting coroutine suspends by calling `delay`. There is no guarantee about which coroutine will be launched first, so if you need to be sure that all values are collected you need to add some kind of additionall synchronization.

Also the collecting coroutine will run indefinitely, so you will have to stop the app manually.

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val eventBus = EventBus()
    launch {
        repeat(5) {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
        delay(5000)
        (5..10).forEach {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
    launch {
        eventBus.value.collect {
            println("value comes before interval $it")
        }
    }
}

class EventBus {
    private val _value = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val value: SharedFlow<Int> = _value.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun increment(number: Int) {
        _value.emit(number)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note launching the collector first is not a proper solution neither. We don't have any guarantees on the order of concurrent coroutines. If we need guarantees that all items are consumed, we have to use synchronization of some sort, flow with a buffer, etc.

Comment: Right, I shall correct it. @broot

Comment: @JanItor can you please explain me what broot mentioned about buffer in flow?. Thanks

Comment: Flow has [buffer](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html) function. Another example here: [Buffering](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#buffering). @VivekModi

Answer (score 0):

I think, The issue in your code is related to the fact that you're using `delay(10.seconds)` after emitting the initial values into the `MutableSharedFlow`. The program is exiting before the second coroutine has a chance to collect the values.

To fix this issue, you should use `delay` in a way that allows the second coroutine to collect the values before the program exits. One way to do this is by using `delay` inside the second coroutine itself. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

fun main() {
    val eventBus = EventBus()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        repeat(10) {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
        delay(10.seconds)
        (10..20).forEach {
            eventBus.increment(it)
        }
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        // Add a delay here or some other mechanism to wait for values to be emitted
        delay(15.seconds)
        eventBus.value.collect {
            println("value comes before interval $it")
        }
    }

    // Add a delay here or some other mechanism to prevent the program from exiting immediately
    Thread.sleep(20000) // Sleep for 20 seconds to allow coroutines to finish
}
```

I've added a `delay(15 seconds)` in the second coroutine to ensure that it waits for values to be emitted before attempting to collect them. Also, I added `Thread.sleep(10000)` at the end of the main function to keep the program alive for 10 seconds, allowing the coroutines to finish their work. You may adjust the duration of the sleep according to your needs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry to say but still not working the code..

Comment: I would try `suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {` and drop the `GlobalScope.` to launch within that scope. However eventbus.collect would need to be terminated some way because it will run indefinitely.